# Problem deploying multiple dash-applications using one configuration file on apache2 server

Tags: flask, apache2, configuration-files, plotly-dash

We are trying to deploy several dash apps by using the same config-file, but different wsgi-files.  Right now this is what we have and when we run it the page says "error loading" layout.

Our configuration file and wsgi-files are shown below:

Config-file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/test/test1:/var/www/test/test2

<VirtualHost *:8084>
    ServerName <example ip>
    ServerAdmin youremail@mail.com

    WSGIScriptAlias /test1 /var/www/test/wsgi-files/test1.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/test/test1/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /test1/static /var/www/test/test1/static
    <Directory /var/www/test/test1/static/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /test2 /var/www/test/wsgi-files/test2.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/test/test2/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /test2/static /var/www/test/test2/static
    <Directory //var/www/test/test2/static/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Wsgi-file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
import logging
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/test/")

from test1 import server as application
```

The second wsgi-file looks like the one above but points at test2 instead.

We have used simple test code from dash as examples and we want the first test application to be found att example.com/test1 and the second application at example.com/test2.

In WSGIScriptAlias if we write “/ /var/www/test/wsgi-files/test1.wsgi” instead of “/test1 /var/www/test/wsgi-files/test1.wsgi”, we get no error but test1-application will appear on every page of the port we are deploying on.  We are rather new to dash, python and web-development so might be a simple answer but we have spent the last hours trying every example we can find. Among other this is something we’ve tried: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/running-mutliple-flask-application.

The app code we are using is shown below.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask

print('Hello this is monkey')
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

server=Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Test 1'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Montreal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

app.css.append_css({"external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"})
server=app.server
@server.route("/test1")
def MyDashApp():
        return app.index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

We would be very thankful for any help.